# Не удается верно указать индексы дублирующихся символов в строке

Tags: c#

Необходимо вывести индексы начала и конца последовательности дублирующихся гласных символов.

Входные данные:

> abc aabc aaabc bcaaaa

Выходные:

> 4 5, 9 11, 17 20

Мой код:

```
string vowels = "eyuioa";
string str = "abc aabc aaabc bcaaaa";
int endInd = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (vowels.Contains(str[i]))
    {
        endInd = i;
        while (vowels.Contains(str[endInd]) && endInd + 1 < str.Length)
        {
            endInd++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} {endInd}\n");
        i = endInd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Дублирующиеся гласные это повторяющиеся буквы: «aa» и «ee»? Или «ae» и «ea» тоже считаются?

Comment: @default locale «ae» и «ea» тоже считаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле будем проверять что следующий (а не текущий) элемент — гласная. Делать это будем после проверки индекса, чтобы не получить исключение:

```
while (endInd + 1 < str.Length && vowels.Contains(str[endInd+1]))
```

Также не будем ничего выводить, если найдена последовательность из одной гласной:

```
if (endInd>i) Console.WriteLine($"{i} {endInd}\n");
```

Вроде больше ошибок не нашел и должно работать.

Такого же результата можно добиться регулярным выражением:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, "[eyuioa]{2,}"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{match.Index} {match.Index+match.Length-1}");
}
```